# will_paginate error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Excuse me I have a problem with will_paginate plugin.

In localhost, in my controller, I use `person.operations.descend_by_date.paginate :page => params[:page] || 1`. However in production the method show error. I think that the problem is thye parameter page. Because person.operation.descend_by_date return a collection i try `passing only params[:page] || 1`.

However in localhost show error. The rare subject is:

If I evaluate the method once => Show error
IF i evaluate the method twice or more times => works ok

Rails show this message error: `hash parameters expected`

Why could be the error?

Comment: You need to include what error is shown when you say "the method show error."

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott excuse Now i edit the post.

Comment: can you try without "|| 1" ... will_paginate will assume 1

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott I now try. However i don´t believe that these was the error

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott Now First i convert the active record object to array and the i use the will_paginate method for array. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i convert the will_paginate object to array and then i use the method for arrays of will_paginate

```
person.operations.descend_by_date.to_a.paginate params[:page] || 1
```

Thanks